# jdbcappender driver org.h2.Driver class

Tags: grails, jdbc, h2, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to use JDBCAppender to log to an H2 database in Grails (using GGTS). Since H2 is the default database in Grails, I shouldn't have to add the h2 jar to the CLASSPATH or set it as a dependency. But when I try to set the driver under the appender to `org.h2.Driver`, a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` is thrown. I've tried just about everything and cannot figure it out. It seems to be a JDBCAppender specific issue. Any solutions to this?

Comment: I made the error go away commenting the fork mode in the `BuildConfig.groovy` but no log is inserted in the database.

Comment: @SérgioMichels That worked and I was able to insert the log into the database. Maybe I can help you? Thank you for your comment!

Comment: Cool! Maybe share your final code as answer.